# How to Disable image button

Tags: jquery

I have an button whose type is image i want to disable button till some action following is the html tag

How to disable this button?

Comment: 19 questions, no answers, no votes, no answers accepted?  I'd say you are abusing the community.  Surely some of the questions you've asked have had helpful answers.

Comment: yes i found some questions were helpful but i need some help how i can accept questions and vote .

Comment: Reference the FAQ link at the top of the page and look at the official FAQ question, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq, on meta.  Basically, you use the up arrow (down for unhelpful answers/questions) next to the answer.  To accept an answer, click the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a click that returns false:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() { return false; });
```

You might want to add a message that explains why it's disabled, and possibly some CSS to make it look disabled as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to disable or re-enable a control:

```
function handleControlDisplay(className, foundCount, checked) {



    var button = jQuery(className);



    if (foundCount > 0 && foundCount == checked) {

        // enable

        button.removeAttr("disabled");

    }

    else {

        // set the disabled attribute

        button.attr("disabled", "true");

    };

}
```